# Finding $C$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}} < C $ where $a\geq 0$

Tags: calculus

I know this problem is on here somewhere, but it required a different approach to what i have here.

Let $ \epsilon > 0 $ be given.
$$ 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |\sqrt x - \sqrt a| < \epsilon$$

We require $C > 0 $ such that

$$|\sqrt x - \sqrt a| = \frac{|x-a|}{|\sqrt x + \sqrt a|} < C |x-a| $$

Since $0 < |x-a| < \delta $ we can take $\delta = 1$

$$|x-a| < 1 $$
$$ \implies a-1 < x < a + 1$$
$$ \implies \sqrt{ a-1} < \sqrt x < \sqrt {a + 1}$$

This is where i simply can't go on. if $a < 1$ which it most certainly can be then were in the complex realm!

But is it ok to treat this as two separate cases? so that

Case 1:
$a > 1$

$$ \implies \sqrt{ a-1} + \sqrt{a} < \sqrt x + \sqrt{a} < \sqrt {a + 1} + \sqrt{a}$$

$$ \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{ a-1} + \sqrt{a}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt x + \sqrt{a} } > \frac{1}{\sqrt {a + 1} + \sqrt{a}}$$

and so $C =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ a-1} + \sqrt{a}}$

Am i going down the correct route, i feel as though i am not, simply because im going to end up with two different values for $C$ when i deal with the case $0 < a \leq 1$ and $a = 0$

Comment: If $x$ is a variable and $a$ is a constant then this is not possible.  Simply let $x\to 0$ then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}}\to \infty$

Comment: When proving that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is a $\delta$ such that $\dots$, it is quite natural that the $\delta$ would depend on $a$ as well as on $\epsilon$. And one cannot expect such a $\delta$ to exist when $a=0$, for $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined if $x\lt 0$.